# Free proton Decay

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics

Can anyone explain why do free protons dont decay in respective or Particle physics basis. ON the basis of binding energy I understand that it is not possible due to mass defect and also by the fermi theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fermi theory is an effective theory and by so is build up with experimental results in mind. It's an ad-hoc theory which accounts for the experimental results of the time so it cannot have an explanation to why proton decay is forbidden.

Free proton $\beta^+$ decay is forbidden only by the fact that the mass of the neutron is slightly greater than the one of the proton and so it's not possible that the proton decays into a neutron by the decay $$p\to n+e^++\nu_e$$ Moreover, the positron and the neutrino add further total mass to the outgoing particles making the mass defect bigger. There's no way in which a free particle con decay into something which has more mass by conservation of energy.

Some GUT theories like the Georgi-Glashow $SU(5)$ model and the Pati-Salam $SO(10)$ model require proton decay like $$p\to e^++\pi^0$$ with the pion decaying into two photons. The theoretical half-life of the proton under this decay is of the order of $10^{31}$ years, so it's pretty rate. Nevertheless particle physicists are trying to find them to give some experimental basis to the mentioned GUTs.

Comment: can you explain what if free proton in actual universe decays. What will be the scenario of daily life and how would it effect physics theory?

Comment: As I said, **if** a proton could decay under our current understanding of the universe, would take so much time that the universe itself might not even exist anymore. $10^{31}$ years is a **very** long time. If the free proton could decay in much smaller timescales surely the universe wouldn't be how it is now.

Comment: why that so? I am unable to get physical overview when you say universe might not exist?

Comment: Well, up until now the age of the universe is of the order $10^{10}$ years. So if you suppose that at the start of the universe all the protons where created (which is a bit of a stretch, but let's suppose so) the by taking $10^{31}$ years to decay it won't be possible for another $\approx 10^{31}-10^{10}$ years to see one decay. As whether the universe will still exist after this long time is another entire question.

Comment: If the proton had a faster decay we would have measure it by now. If a faster decay existed who knows how the universe would be by now.